# eclipse shortcut assign new object to existing variable

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I have the following code.

```
someMethod() {
     Connection connection = null;

     try {
          ds.getConection();
```

At this point, is there any shortcut to assign the new connection to the variable `connection`.
I'm able to assign the new `Connection` to a new variable(Ctrl -2 L) but not existing one.

Answer (score 0):

One option is you can assign `ds.getConection();` to a field using:

> **(Ctrl + 2 f)**

But for this don't declare `Connection connection = null;` eclipse will take care of this declaration.